# Does anyone know how to create two vlan on a Askey RTF8115VW router?

Tags: networking, router, vlan

Does anyone know how to create 2 different vlan on a Askey RTF8115VW router?

I would like to be able to create two different vlan, one for the first port and another one for the second one. I would also like to be able to configure its own dhcp server for each vlan each network would use different ip nets or subnets.

Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 0):

From the manuals I've found, it does not seem that the device supports multiple VLANs at all.

Comment: Were you able to check the advanced setting UI? There you can find bridging, marking & filtering menus which look like it's possible but I feel them a litle confusing.